# Compiling with icc -static issue

Tags: c++, linux, icc

I have been using ICC to compile a program I wrote for my research (nothing impressive just a lot of floating point calculations) and I can compile it just fine using:

```
 g++ -O3 mixingModel.cpp configFile.cpp -o mixingModel
```

or

```
 icc -O3 -ipo -static mixingModel.cpp configFile.cpp -o mixingModel
```

However, as soon as I add -static the compiler just hangs. This issue first crept up when I wanted to use -fast and the compiler just sat there compiling away forever. The process that is running is called mcpcom and it takes 99% of my cpu (so its one thread) and hardly any memory. I have let it sit there for over 30 minutes before (usual compile time without -fast is under one minutes).

I then went ahead and wrote a small hello world program in c++ and tried compiling it with the -fast flag and it again showed the same MO. Sat there with 99% cpu used and the process called is mcpcom.

Note: I am compiling on 64bit Linux with ICC version 11.1 20100806

Thank you,

Patrick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely due to icc's inter-procedural optimization. It considers all object files, which can be a lot when doing static linking. So I recommend to drop `-ipo`. Apparently, this is an [old problem](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=47032).

Comment: I think you are right I just removed -ipo and compiled it again and it works. Why though does this happen when there is only one source file as in my test case of it failing with a simple hello world program?

Comment: Even though you have only one object file, the libraries you are linking have hundreds (there is really no way to go without stdio, for example, which then brings malloc and the rest of the standard library). So the compiler tries to find optimization potential/inlining across these object files.